# ios stop animation when UIViewController not been displayed

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, optimization

Animation or something else will cost CPU. If a ViewController not on screen, e.g. The ViewController not at the top of the navigation stack. Should I stop them to reduce CPU cost? Will it enhance the performance of my apps? What is the best practices to do this? any blogs about this?

I searched whth google, but find nothing.

Any reply will be appreciate, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,  you should stop animation if it is not visible.
You can do it in different places based on your implementation. I don't know what kind of animations are you using (based on OpenGL, timer, CAAnimation or other technologies), but next methods are common:

1. Method of a Application Delegate ["Application will resign Active"](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive).
2. Method of a ViewController ["View will disappear"](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621485-viewwilldisappear) or ["View did disappear"](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621477-viewdiddisappear).
3. Method of a View ["Will move to window"](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622563-willmovetowindow) or ["Did move to window"](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiview/1622527-didmovetowindow), when destination window == nil.

Also do not't forget that CAAnimations is [stopped by system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9294466/layer-animations-removed-when-switching-apps) then your application moves to background.