# resume animation app if app enter foreground ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, animation

I have a small problem, when my application enter the background the animation stop and don't resume when the application goes back to the foreground.

I have tried this:

```
@implementation startViewController

-(void)animation {

    UIImage*img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wolk2.png"];
    image1 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img1];
    image1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 400, 200);

    UIImage*img2= [UIImage imageNamed:@"wolk1.png"];
    image2 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img2];
    image2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 220, 100);

    [self.imageView addSubview:image1];
    [self.imageView addSubview:image2];
    [[self imageView]sendSubviewToBack:image1];
    [[self imageView]sendSubviewToBack:image2];



    CGFloat a = (CGFloat) (100);
    CGFloat b = (CGFloat) (100);
    CGFloat a1 = (CGFloat) (50);
    CGFloat b1 = (CGFloat) (350);
    CGPoint startPointOne=CGPointMake(a,b);
    CGPoint startPointTwo=CGPointMake(a1,b1);
    image1.center=startPointOne;
    image2.center=startPointTwo;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:20];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:100000];

    CGFloat c = (CGFloat) (700);
    CGFloat d = (CGFloat) (100);
    CGPoint endPointOne=CGPointMake(c,d);
    image1.center = endPointOne;


    [UIView commitAnimations];

    [UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:30];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatAutoreverses:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationRepeatCount:100000];

    CGFloat c1 = (CGFloat) (650);
    CGFloat d1 = (CGFloat) (350);
    CGPoint endPointTwo=CGPointMake(c1,d1);
    image2.center = endPointTwo;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Then in the app delegate I have enter this:

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
 start = [[startViewController alloc]init];
        [start animation];

    }
```

But this didn't work, so what should I do to resume the animation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568567/restoring-animation-where-it-left-off-when-app-resumes-from-background

Answer (score 0):

You are create an new instance of your `startViewController`:

```
 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
      start = [[startViewController alloc]init];
      [start animation];
 }
```

You should call the existing instance of the `startViewController`, it could be something like:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  [self.startViewController animation];
}
```

Where the `self.startViewController` is a property where you retain the instance of your `startViewController`.

Comment: Which part? You are sure that you are keeping the correct reference to the instance of `startViewController`?