# Pause and Resume UIViewAnimation when app goes to background

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I am animating a view and I want to pause it and resume it.

Using an apple guide I created a CALayer Extension

```
extension CALayer {

    func pause() {
        var pauseTime = self.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), fromLayer: nil)
        self.speed = 0.0
        self.timeOffset = pauseTime
    }

    func resume() {
        var pausedTime = self.timeOffset
        self.speed = 1.0
        self.timeOffset = 0.0
        self.beginTime = 0.0
        var timeSincePause = self.convertTime(CACurrentMediaTime(), toLayer: nil) - pausedTime

        self.beginTime = timeSincePause
    }
}
```

This code is working perfectly except when that app goes to background. When I bring the App back to foreground animations is finished (even if the time is not pass) and it is not starting again when I click resume.

Ok. I tried animating CALayer but I have the same problem.

```
extension CALayer {

   func animateY(newY:CGFloat,time:NSTimeInterval,completion:()->Void){
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")
    animation.fromValue = self.position.y
    animation.toValue  = newY
    animation.duration = time
    animation.delegate = self
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)
    animation.removedOnCompletion = false // don't remove after finishing
    self.position.y = newY
    self.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "position.y")
    CATransaction.flush()

  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting `removedOnCompletion=NO;` for you animation. That should stop it being removed.

Comment: You can also add an observer for the notification event `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` inside which you can rejig your animation. You can treat this like `viewWillAppear` as it is not called on resume from background.

Comment: there's a ton of duplicate questions on this, including the answer to "Restoring animation where it left off when app resumes from background". See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568567/restoring-animation-where-it-left-off-when-app-resumes-from-background/7983292#7983292

Comment: You haven`t noticed that i tried the method in the answer and is not working for me. :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `CABasicAnimation`. Your resume/pause methods should be fine, since they are from this [answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3003922/2088620) You should try using `Core Animation` instead of `UIViewAnimation` and then the resume/pause will work.

Then you can register for the two notifications `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` and `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` to have full control over the pause/resume actions.

Comment: That is the same code as the question code, just not implemented as a CALayer extension.

Comment: Yeah, but he is using UIViewAnimation instead of Core Animation. That is why I think his code has no effect, because it should be used with a layer animation.