# CALayer disappears after playing a CABasicAnimation backwards

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, calayer, cabasicanimation

I have a CALayer and I've added a CABasicAnimation to it like this:

```
circle = CALayer()
circle.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
circle.backgroundColor = UIColor.green().cgColor
circle.cornerRadius = 50
circle.speed = 0
view.layer.addSublayer(circle)

animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position")
animation.duration = 1
animation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
animation.toValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: view.bounds.width / 2, y: view.bounds.height / 2))
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false
circle.add(animation, forKey: nil)
```

When I play the animation backwards by setting the layer's speed to `-1`,
the layer disappears at the end of the animation:

```
circle.timeOffset = 1
circle.speed = -1
circle.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
```

Because of that, I use CADisplayLink to play an animation backwards,
but I'm wondering if it can be achieved by setting the speed to `-1` and preventing the layer from disappearing also.

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Had the same issue, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65683369/resume-cabasicanimation-backwards-by-setting-speed-equal-to-1 for solution.