# How to make iOS swift block animation inside Custom UIView perpetual?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

### Current Code

Currently I have the following code for [`AnimationView.swift`](https://gist.github.com/AlanCPSC/1566c40b55556b8c875af05472f5e19e)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AnimationView: UIView {

    private let backgroundView = UIView()
    private let foregroundView = UIView()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
...
```

And also I have the following code for [`ViewController.swift`](https://gist.github.com/AlanCPSC/7e43cec52935aa19e4757bf746657735)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let x = AnimationView(frame: .zero)
...
```

### Problem

The block animation code has issues related to the view controller's life cycle and whether or not it was added to the view hierarchy before calling `UIView.animate(...)`. Ideally, I want the animation to just run continuously on a loop without any interruptions or concerns about these factors. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.0, delay: 0, options: [.autoreverse, .repeat], animations: {
    self.foregroundView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.3, y: 0.3)
}, completion: nil)
```

### Screenshots

[image]

Comment: So, viewDidAppear is called every time....well, your view appears. So, each time you reopen your application to that screen it creates another AnimationView and adds it to the hierarchy.

Comment: Run your code in the simulator. Open the app and home back (do this a couple times). While keeping the simulator running, go to Xcode, go to the debug session (spray can with an x), on the left hand side there is a panel with your app name and to the right a circle with a couple of lines. Click this circle and go to view UI hierarchy. This will show you how many views have been added as well as their properties.

Comment: You could also use the viewDidLoad method to create the view and use viewWillAppear/Disappear methods to remove the animation and restart it.

Comment: @ChrisTech44 Your last suggestion would require a `CustomView: UIView` to be aware of the view controller's lifecycle. Is it possible to create a custom view that is completely disjoint from the VC that just "works"?

Comment: @ChrisTech44 I do not believe `viewDidAppear` is called by sending the app to be background and then returning the app to the foreground. Of course if the app is killed and restarted then `viewDidAppear` will be called but then it's a whole new instance of the app and view controller.

Comment: @AlanSTACK - do you need the animation to ***resume*** from its current state? Or, would re-starting the animation be ok?

Comment: @DonMag Restarting will be fine. No need for exact state continuity. As long as the animation is running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question *could* be closed as a duplicate, but because there are a couple things that are different and the solution may not completely obvious I'm posting this answer...

For reference, this would be the duplicate post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50074722/6257435

and the related code can be found here: https://gist.github.com/ArtFeel/ad4b108f026e53723c7457031e291bc8

However, links can go away, so I'll include all the code below.

First, as mentioned in the comments, you are adding a new instance of your animation view every time `viewDidAppear()` is called. So, let's move the view creation to `viewDidLoad()`:

```
class PersistentAnimationViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        // do this here in viewDidLoad
        //  NOT in viewDidAppear!
        let x = AnimationView(frame: .zero)
        x.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        view.addSubview(x)
        
        x.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        x.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        x.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        x.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.heightAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
}
```

Next, it's generally a bad idea to start animations (or other activity) in a class `init`, so we'll put the animation code in `didMoveToSuperview()` instead.

Also, you were executing `foregroundView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2` during init, when the view may or may not have a frame. That should go in `layoutSubviews()`.

We can get better control of animations by using `CABasicAnimation` instead of `UIView.animate(...)`, so we'll make that change as well.

Finally, we'll use the referenced extensions and custom layer subclass to enable the animation to pause/resume when the app goes into / comes back from the background.

So, your `AnimationView` class (modified):

```
class AnimationView: UIView {
    
    private let backgroundView = UIView()
    private let foregroundView = UIView()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    private func commonInit() {
        // setting up the views
        backgroundView.backgroundColor = .green
        foregroundView.backgroundColor = .orange
        
        // if you want rounded corners (or a "circle" view)
        //  put this in layoutSubviews()
        //foregroundView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.width / 2
        
        // adding the views
        addSubview(backgroundView)
        addSubview(foregroundView)
        
        // activating the views
        backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foregroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            backgroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            backgroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
            backgroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            backgroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
            
            foregroundView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor),
            foregroundView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor),
            foregroundView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor),
            foregroundView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor),
        ])
        
        // make the layer animation
        //  pause when app goes to background
        //  resume when app comes to foreground
        // see below
        self.foregroundView.layer.makeAnimationsPersistent()
    }
    
    // don't start the animation during init
    //  this is a reasonable place
    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()

        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath:"transform.scale.xy")
        animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        animation.fromValue = 1.0
        animation.toValue = 0.3
        // set desired timing, or leave it at the default
        //animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: CAMediaTimingFunctionName.easeInEaseOut)
        animation.duration = 2.0
        animation.repeatCount = .infinity
        animation.autoreverses = true
        self.foregroundView.layer.add(animation, forKey: "scale")
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // here in layoutSubviews we have a valid frame/bounds
        //  so do anything like rounding corners, etc
        foregroundView.layer.cornerRadius = bounds.width / 2
    }
    
}
```

and the required extension / layer subclass code:

```
// from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50074722/6257435
// extensions and LayerPersistentHelper class found here:
//  https://gist.github.com/ArtFeel/ad4b108f026e53723c7457031e291bc8
public extension CALayer {
    var isAnimationsPaused: Bool {
        return speed == 0.0
    }
    
    func pauseAnimations() {
        if !isAnimationsPaused {
            let currentTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
            let pausedTime = convertTime(currentTime, from: nil)
            speed = 0.0
            timeOffset = pausedTime
        }
    }
    
    func resumeAnimations() {
        let pausedTime = timeOffset
        speed = 1.0
        timeOffset = 0.0
        beginTime = 0.0
        let currentTime = CACurrentMediaTime()
        let timeSincePause = convertTime(currentTime, from: nil) - pausedTime
        beginTime = timeSincePause
    }
}

public extension CALayer {
    static private var persistentHelperKey = "CALayer.LayerPersistentHelper"
    
    func makeAnimationsPersistent() {
        var object = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &CALayer.persistentHelperKey)
        if object == nil {
            object = LayerPersistentHelper(with: self)
            let nonatomic = objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &CALayer.persistentHelperKey, object, nonatomic)
        }
    }
}

public class LayerPersistentHelper {
    private var persistentAnimations: [String: CAAnimation] = [:]
    private var persistentSpeed: Float = 0.0
    private weak var layer: CALayer?
    
    public init(with layer: CALayer) {
        self.layer = layer
        addNotificationObservers()
    }
    
    deinit {
        removeNotificationObservers()
    }
}

private extension LayerPersistentHelper {
    func addNotificationObservers() {
        let center = NotificationCenter.default
        let enterForeground = UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification
        let enterBackground = UIApplication.didEnterBackgroundNotification
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didBecomeActive), name: enterForeground, object: nil)
        center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive), name: enterBackground, object: nil)
    }
    
    func removeNotificationObservers() {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
    
    func persistAnimations(with keys: [String]?) {
        guard let layer = self.layer else { return }
        keys?.forEach { (key) in
            if let animation = layer.animation(forKey: key) {
                persistentAnimations[key] = animation
            }
        }
    }
    
    func restoreAnimations(with keys: [String]?) {
        guard let layer = self.layer else { return }
        keys?.forEach { (key) in
            if let animation = persistentAnimations[key] {
                layer.add(animation, forKey: key)
            }
        }
    }
}

@objc extension LayerPersistentHelper {
    func didBecomeActive() {
        guard let layer = self.layer else { return }
        restoreAnimations(with: Array(persistentAnimations.keys))
        persistentAnimations.removeAll()
        if persistentSpeed == 1.0 { // if layer was playing before background, resume it
            layer.resumeAnimations()
        }
    }
    
    func willResignActive() {
        guard let layer = self.layer else { return }
        persistentSpeed = layer.speed
        layer.speed = 1.0 // in case layer was paused from outside, set speed to 1.0 to get all animations
        persistAnimations(with: layer.animationKeys())
        layer.speed = persistentSpeed // restore original speed
        layer.pauseAnimations()
    }
}
```